# Hide elements from Array Adapter, not remove them

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, google-places-api

I am trying to hide some elements in my Array Adapter of AutoCompleteTextView from google places api. More spesific i want to hide the elements tha their `position%2==0`. I found some answers in stack overflow that suggests to do this in getView like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(position%2==0) {
        //something to do here
    }
    return view;
}
```

but I do not know what I have to do in the comment area.

Here is the whole code:

```
class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList resultList;

    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(position%2==0) {
            //view.setVisibility() maybe?
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in `getCount()` and `getItem()`:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size() / 2;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index * 2 + 1);
}
```

Just make sure you use `getItem()` within `getView()`.

Comment: Thanks kris. It worked! Not sure what you mean in: Just make sure you use getItem() within getView(). part. I did not had to do this

Comment: Just that you wouldn't have to duplicate the formula resultList index = position * 2 + 1.  That will make sure you get the correct item out of the list.  Now, the superclass `getView` already uses `getItem` so if you didn't override `getView` you don't have to worry about anything, because the superclass will do the right thing.